# Need to send Publish Test result chart in Email notification

Tags: azure, junit, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, junit-runner

I need to capture image form publish test result and that captured image needs to send in an email.

is this possible in Azure DevOps ci/cd pipeline?

I have attached below screenshot for reference.

Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not available as an out of the box feature as of today, AFAIK. At most, you can see the stats of the latest test run included in the build completion email notification with a link to the see them on the Portal.

However, you can search for suitable Azure DevOps extensions in the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/azuredevops), or submit your suggestion at the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) for Azure DevOps for our Team to look at.